# Blazor server, additional assemblies for Router component does not respect @page declaration

Tags: c#, routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have multiple assemblies that contain my razor pages.
I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-to-components-from-multiple-assemblies), so I have specified the array of these assemblies in the Router component.

The problem is that the pages in my assemblies seem to all have the route '/'.

> ```
> InvalidOperationException: the following routes are ambigous:
> '/' in 'OtherComponents.Pages.ConfigPage'
> '/' in 'MyApp.Pages.Index'
> ```

ConfigPage.razor in OtherComponents.dll assembly

```
@page "/config"
@inherits ConfigPageBase

<h1>Configuration Page</h1>
```

Index.razor in MyApp assembly

```
@page "/"

<h1>IndexPage</h1>
```

If I change the route of page `Index.razor` (to '/index' for example), then the '/' route load correctly the `ConfigPage.razor`. I suppose the pages are correctly loaded from additional assemblies but without respect the `@page` definition.

Comment: I'd suggest cleaning all the projects, then deleting the `/bin` and `/obj` folders, then rebuilding. There should not be a conflict here., I've used imported modules with routed pages and it does work